# setOrdinal not working properly when table is bind to datasource

Tags: c#

When I try to add new column and use `SetOrdinal(2)`

The newly added column was positioned in the last column

```
 conn = new MySqlConnection(connectString);
 conn.Open();
 fireAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
 fireBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(fireAdapter);
 fireDataTable = new DataTable();
 fireAdapter.Fill(fireDataTable);
 fireSource = new BindingSource();
 fireSource.DataSource = fireDataTable;
 grid.DataSource = fireSource;
 conn.Close();

 DataColumn newcol = new DataColumn("Blah", typeof(string));
 fireDataTable.Columns.Add(newcol);
 newcol.SetOrdinal(2);
```

Comment: I even tried all that solution but no luck.

Comment: Please see my code above

Comment: @ywwy that line of code is not working you cannot set an ordinal after `Add(newcol)` it gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your code does what you expect, it changes the position of the new column in the `DataTable`. But it is still shown as last column in the grid. So why you don't initialize the `BindingSource` **after** you have fully initialized the `DataTable`?

```
DataColumn newcol = new DataColumn("Blah", typeof(string));
fireDataTable.Columns.Add(newcol);
newcol.SetOrdinal(2);
// and now start assign it to the BindingSource
```

Comment: Well that was quick,